# Trouble iterating through a nested list using a for loop to edit the inner lists

Tags: python, loops, nested-lists

I just can't figure out how to manage some arp tables. The only data that is relevant to me is the ip address and the mac address listed. I don't know if I should,

1. iterate through the `nested_list`, removing `[0, 2, 4, 5]`
2. iterate through the lists, assigning `[1]` and `[3]` to new lists.

I have tried both ways and I'm just not getting there. My syntax knowledge is clearly lacking.

Before any of the code you're about to see I start by accessing a file using `with`/`as` and use `.readlines()` to create a list of strings I call `read_output`.

Here is my code as it stands now:

```
nested_list = []

for index in read_output: 
    nested_list.append(index.split()) #this creates the nested list.

print(nested_list)
```

Which works fine and gives me this output as example:

```
[['Internet', '10.220.88.1', '135', '0062.ec29.70fe', 'ARPA', 'FastEthernet4'],
 ['Internet', '10.220.88.40', '144', '001c.c4bf.826a', 'ARPA', 'FastEthernet4']]
```

The arp list can be a lot bigger than this but I thought I would save some space for our example. I want to be able to go through the list and add/remove/extract data as I see fit but every time I try I am met with varying degrees of failure.

If i just:

```
print(nested_list[0][3])
```

I get the expected result of `0062.ec29.70fe` but when I try to use a second for loop to access every `[n][0]`, `[n][2]`, etc., things go horribly awry.

I'm starting with:

```
for index in read_output:
    nested_list.append(index.split())
    for indx in nested_list:
    # --->insert some horrible excuse for python here
```

My intended output is taking the nested list above and trimming it down to:

```
[['10.220.88.1', '0062.ec29.70fe'],
 ['10.220.88.40', '001c.c4bf.826a']]
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  Please read and follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation.  [Minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) applies here.  We cannot effectively help you until you post your MCVE code and accurately describe the problem.
We should be able to paste your posted code into a text file and reproduce the problem you described.

Comment: In this code, I'm not sure what you want for output: on one hand, you cite needing locations 1 & 3 from each line; in another, you talk about iterating through the other four elements.  Also, from whence comes this `pprint` command you're using?  This isn't a Python built-in.  Once you've clarified, I expect we can solve your problem in a couple of minutes.

Comment: apologies, as for as pprint it can mostly be disregarded, its just 'from pprint import pprint' and helps with the formatting of long things. all I really need is to be able to loop through the nested list and delete unneeded data. every time i attempt this i end up deleting everything or nothing or generating an error.

Comment: I have edited the code and removed pprint as advised as it doesn't change the output i'm looking for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't append the whole sub-list in the first place but only the two items you want:

```
nested_list = []

for index in read_output: 
    inner = index.split()
    nested_list.append([inner[1], inner[3]])
```

Comment: Is it really that simple? I knew i was over-thinking. Going to try this soon and  it sounds like this is what i'm looking for. thank you so much.

Comment: Great that it helped. BTW, you can [accept](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) an answer if it solves your problem. Just click on the check mark (✓) next to the answer. This will toggle it from grayed-out to filled-in.

Comment: Just tried it out and got the exact output I was expecting. much appreciated. answer accepted!

Answer (score 0):

Alright so I hope I'm understanding this correctly, but from what I understand, you're getting your data correctly, which is this:

```
[['Internet', '10.220.88.1', '135', '0062.ec29.70fe', 'ARPA', 
'FastEthernet4'],
 ['Internet', '10.220.88.40', '144', '001c.c4bf.826a', 'ARPA', 
'FastEthernet4']]
```

So you're correct in seeing that this is actually a list, containing two sub-lists.  We can take advantage of this in our code below.

```
list = [['Internet', '10.220.88.1', '135', '0062.ec29.70fe', 'ARPA', 'FastEthernet4'],['Internet', '10.220.88.40', '144', '001c.c4bf.826a', 'ARPA', 'FastEthernet4']]
```

So now that we've contained that list, similar to how you did, we can loop through that list.

```
for item in list:
    print ("IP: {0}\nMac Address:{1}\n".format(item[1],item[3]))
```

This gave me the output that I hope you're expecting which is:

```
IP: 10.220.88.1
Mac Address: 0062.ec29.70fe

IP: 10.220.88.40
Mac Address: 001c.c4bf.826a
```

So what we did is run a loop through the outer list, and since we knew that the IP address was always going to be at index of 1 and 3 of the inner list, we just accessed them through their index.

You don't need to run another loop through the inner lists since you already have this knowledge of their placement.

To store these addresses you'd probably want to store them in a 
dictionary since you have a key, value pair kind of setup.

```
address = {}
count += 1
for item in list:
    count += 1
    address["list: {0}".format(count)] = [item[1], item[3]]
    print ("IP: {0}".format(item[1])
    print ("Mac Address: {0}".format(item[3]))
    print ()
print (address)
```

With this we set a count to increase our key name, and with each new list, we saved the two specific values we wanted in another list.
A good challenge would be to see how you could convert it to a form where your key is the ip and mac and your values are, well the values.
I thought about doing that but it even boggled my mind a bit and I wanted to get my answer out to you quickly.  Hope this helps!

Comment: This is also super helpful. The other solution fixed my problem now but this is going to be helpful in making the data more useful and accessable later. thank you!

Comment: Of course, no problem, and I'm glad it all worked out!